# Error with scss when importing to index.js

Tags: reactjs, skeleton-code

I have installed node sass
converted my css to scss. Imported my main.scss into my index.js. Then I try to run it and I get that error.

[Error I am getting in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ54o.png)

Comment: Could you provide the content of your `main.scss` file please?

Answer (score 1):

Your scss files are being parsed by babel-loader which is causing the above error. If you are using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), you need to add [sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#root) into the config to parse the required files.

If you are using `create-react-app`, you need to install [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) and it should work.

`$ npm install node-sass --save-dev`